# How to count if the previous value meets a certain condition in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I want to count the number of times there is a 1 in the `up` column after a 1, the number of 0 after a 1, the number of 1 after two times 1, and so on.

This is my dataset:

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(321)
df <- data.frame(seq(ymd_h("2017-01-01-00"), ymd_h("2020-01-31-24"), by = "hours"))
df$close <- rnorm(nrow(df), 3000, 150)
df$up <- ifelse(sign(rnorm(27025))==-1,0,1)

colnames(df) <- c("date", "close", "up")
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df$hour <- hour(df$date)
df$day <- day(df$date)
df$month <- month(df$date)
df$year <- year(df$date)`
```

I want to count the number of times there is a 1 in the `up` column after a 1, the number of times there is a 0 after a 1, the number of times there is a 1 after two 1 in a row, and so on.
How can I do this with this dataset?

Comment: What is the difference in the first case and 1 after two 1

Comment: For example, I want to know how many times I have a 1 after a single 1; and how many times I have a 1 after two 1. See this: ``0,0,1,1,0`` This count as the a-one after a 1, and this: ``0,1,1,1,0`` count as a 1 after two ones. There is overlap but I want to count different things, the last situation will be counted as 2 times in the first case and one time in the second case.

Comment: what if there is `0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0` or `0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0`

Comment: I will be counted as 3 for the first case, and 1 for the second case. The second will be counted as 4 in the first case and 2 in the second case. I also want to count the number of 1 after a 0 and 1. In this situation, both scenarios will be counted as 1.  I think I can use any idea and try to build something from there because I am kind of lost on this and don't know where to start. In fact what I really need is to create a proportion of times in which after there is a 1 the conditions are meet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a count_01 by taking the `sum` of compound logical expressions created by checking the current value is 1 and previous as 0, then do a group by `rleid` on the 'up' and include 'count_01', `summarise` to return logical columns for 'count_11', 'count_111' where TRUE is only if the number of rows are 2 or 3 respectively and `all` values in 'up' are 1, then take the `sum` of those columns to return the count

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
    mutate(count_01  = sum(up == 1 & lag(up == 0))) %>%
    group_by(group = rleid(up), count_01) %>%
    summarise(count_11 = n() ==2 & all(up == 1),
    count_111 = n() == 3 & all(up == 1), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    summarise(count_01 = first(count_01), count_11 = sum(count_11), 
          count_111 = sum(count_111))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  count_01 count_11 count_111
#     <int>    <int>     <int>
#1     6657     1722       794
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
with(df, sum(up[-1] == 1 & up[-length(up)] == 0))
#[1] 6657
rl <- rle(df$up == 1)
sum(rl$lengths == 3 & rl$values)
#[1] 794
sum(rl$lengths == 2 & rl$values)
#[1] 1722
```

Comment: Thank you!! But for some reason, the data said that there is no 1 after 0. Do you know why? The first column of the output gives: count_01 has 0 observations

Comment: @PastorSoto I get 6657 cases with your data

Comment: There was no set seed in your example

Comment: The base R answer gives me the actual results but the dplyr solution gives me different results. Not sure why

Comment: @PastorSoto Are there any NA elements in the up column

Comment: No. There are no NA elements in any column in the dataset

Comment: @PastorSoto In that case, may be some version difference in packages.  Not sure as I am able to replicate output in both

Comment: @PastorSoto can you check if you have loaded `plyr` also.  In that case, use `dplyr::summarise` to avoid masking

Comment: Yes. I even restart the session and copy and paste everything from here. Now the first column gives me NA but I check for missing values and everything is good. It might be different version of the package I guess

Comment: @PastorSoto can you try `lag(up == 0, default = 999)`

Comment: Yes!! That's the answer. It works now. Thank you!!

Comment: The main problem was ``lag`` was masked. The issue was solve by placing dplyr::lag()

Comment: @PastorSoto `lag` is a common function that can be found in `stats` or in other package.  It is better to use `::`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232182/discussion-between-pastor-soto-and-akrun).